# How do I get the matches from (\s\d+)\s for each lsof output line

Tags: regex, bash

I'm getting active connections using `lsof -i | grep -E "(LISTEN|ESTABLISHED)"` and I want to get the first number:
Example

```
Coda\x202   551 username   46u  IPv4 0x8c39e71075d65ab7      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.35:62283->192.168.0.187:6942 (ESTABLISHED)
Coda\x202   551 username   47u  IPv4 0x8c39e710759c6c57      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.35:6942->192.168.0.37:59833 (ESTABLISHED)
Coda\x202   551 username   50u  IPv4 0x8c39e710759c6c57      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.35:6942->192.168.0.37:59833 (ESTABLISHED)
firefox     981 username   70u  IPv4 0x8c39e71070895867      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.35:61753->ec2-52-35-204-251.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:https ESTABLISHED)
Google    16045 username   83u  IPv4 0x8c39e71078aba387      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.35:62596->109.239.193.10:https (ESTABLISHED)
Google    16045 username   84u  IPv4 0x8c39e71075f52df7      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.35:63819->ham02s15-in-f195.1e100.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
```

551, 981 and 16045

So I can group all the connections based on the ID and print them into separated files.

After fiddling around with regex I got this expression
`(\s\d+)\s` which matches the numbers I want, but I can't get it into my bash script.
I'm not sure whether sed, awk or grep etc. is more appropriate.

Comment: What is your expected output for your input provided?

Comment: How about using tr + cut?
`lsof -i | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f2,10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to keep your grep...

```
lsof -i | grep -E "(LISTEN|ESTABLISHED)" | awk '{print $2}'
```

Here you are using `awk` to `print` the second column (`$2`)

Comment: How is the output of this command different from my answer? This one just adds an unnecessary `grep` to `awk`.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `grep` with an `awk` to print only the 2nd column:

```
lsof -i | awk '/(LISTEN|ESTABLISHED)/{print $2}'
```

This is assuming firs and second column don't have any whitespaces in output of `lsof`.

Comment: Wanted to clarify with the OP, may be he wanted only unique entries?

Comment: Oh ok, question title didn't mention anything about uniques. But if it is needed, awk will be able to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

```
lsof -i | awk '/LISTEN|ESTABLISHED/&&!a[$2]++{print $2}'
```